# Getting xml error while using Camel ActiveMQ

Tags: xml, apache-camel

i need to do some customization with Camel ActiveMQ. So that I can read data and push it to a queue. i have a xml file. Project build is OK. While executing the program i am getting xml error.

**Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext app = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "config/my.xml");
        System.out.println("reading done");
    }
```

**my.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium/spring-osgi-compendium.xsd
         http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
         http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd">

    <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
    </bean>

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route>
            <from uri="timer://MyTimer?fixedRate=true&amp;period=4000" />
            <setBody>
                <constant>Hello World!</constant>
            </setBody>
            <to uri="activemq:camel.timer" />
        </route>
        <route>
            <from uri="activemq:camel.timer" />
            <to uri="file:C:/temp/sandpit/timer" />
        </route>
    </camelContext>

</beans>
```

**ERROR**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to create the JAXB binder; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}propertyDefinition". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.apache.camel.model.config.PropertyDefinition
        at private java.util.List org.apache.camel.model.config.PropertiesDefinition.properties
        at org.apache.camel.model.config.PropertiesDefinition
        at private org.apache.camel.model.config.PropertiesDefinition org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.properties
        at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.apache.camel.model.PropertyDefinition
        at private java.util.List org.apache.camel.core.xml.AbstractCamelEndpointFactoryBean.properties
        at org.apache.camel.core.xml.AbstractCamelEndpointFactoryBean
        at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelEndpointFactoryBean
        at private java.util.List org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.endpoints
        at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean

 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}propertyDefinition". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.apache.camel.model.config.PropertyDefinition
        at private java.util.List org.apache.camel.model.config.PropertiesDefinition.properties
        at org.apache.camel.model.config.PropertiesDefinition
        at private org.apache.camel.model.config.PropertiesDefinition org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.properties
        at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.apache.camel.model.PropertyDefinition
        at private java.util.List org.apache.camel.core.xml.AbstractCamelEndpointFactoryBean.properties
        at org.apache.camel.core.xml.AbstractCamelEndpointFactoryBean
        at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelEndpointFactoryBean
        at private java.util.List org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.endpoints
        at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean
]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler$CamelContextBeanDefinitionParser.doParse(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:59)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1438)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.ambika.testmq.ReadDataFromTCPPort.main(ReadDataFromTCPPort.java:8)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}propertyDefinition". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.apache.camel.model.config.PropertyDefinition
        at private java.util.List org.apache.camel.model.config.PropertiesDefinition.properties
        at org.apache.camel.model.config.PropertiesDefinition
        at private org.apache.camel.model.config.PropertiesDefinition org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.properties
        at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.apache.camel.model.PropertyDefinition
        at private java.util.List org.apache.camel.core.xml.AbstractCamelEndpointFactoryBean.properties
        at org.apache.camel.core.xml.AbstractCamelEndpointFactoryBean
        at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelEndpointFactoryBean
        at private java.util.List org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.endpoints
        at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean

 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}propertyDefinition". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.apache.camel.model.config.PropertyDefinition
        at private java.util.List org.apache.camel.model.config.PropertiesDefinition.properties
        at org.apache.camel.model.config.PropertiesDefinition
        at private org.apache.camel.model.config.PropertiesDefinition org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.properties
        at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.apache.camel.model.PropertyDefinition
        at private java.util.List org.apache.camel.core.xml.AbstractCamelEndpointFactoryBean.properties
        at org.apache.camel.core.xml.AbstractCamelEndpointFactoryBean
        at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelEndpointFactoryBean
        at private java.util.List org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.endpoints
        at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean
]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler.createJaxbContext(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:188)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler.getJaxbContext(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:175)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler$CamelContextBeanDefinitionParser.doParse(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:303)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}propertyDefinition". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.apache.camel.model.config.PropertyDefinition
        at private java.util.List org.apache.camel.model.config.PropertiesDefinition.properties
        at org.apache.camel.model.config.PropertiesDefinition
        at private org.apache.camel.model.config.PropertiesDefinition org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.properties
        at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.apache.camel.model.PropertyDefinition
        at private java.util.List org.apache.camel.core.xml.AbstractCamelEndpointFactoryBean.properties
        at org.apache.camel.core.xml.AbstractCamelEndpointFactoryBean
        at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelEndpointFactoryBean
        at private java.util.List org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.endpoints
        at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean

    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    ... 31 more
```

Can anybody help me ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the extraneous namespaces as a starting point.

Change your beans tag to

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
```

Comment: If that does not work, which version of Camel are you using? Camel 1 requires a different namespace:  http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring
http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd

Comment: Thanks jirawat for the reply. i have modified the xml file as per your suggestion. But its not solving the issue. i am getting same error. I am using Camel 2.15.3 version jars.

Comment: issue solved. the main issue was that there were some Camel 2.12 jars in my build path. So i removed them

Answer (score 0):

Simply elaborating the comment by @user940782 again so that the answer is not missed.

I am using embedded Activemq to deploy my Camel Based Application.
My Activemq v5.10.1 uses Camel v2.13.1
My camel application was using v2.16.0

Based on the comment, I changed the Camel version in my application to 2.13.1
And the issue was resolved.